# how can send new added item in nested object as response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with name User in my mongodb for the example you can see in below a sample of saved user

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61488f3892099143ca2b2bbc"),
  name: 'test',
  orders: [],
  products: [
    {
      name: 'as',
      image: '049fcd8d-f954-4aef-bd77-757af881f7c5.jpeg',
      _id: new ObjectId("61531666ad63a47ed692c90b")
    },
  ]
}
```

I have function with node.js that has responsible to add new product to selected user

```
async function addProduct(req, res, next) {
  await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.userId },
    {
      $addToSet: {
        products: {
          ...req.body,
          image: req.file.filename,
        },
      },
    }
  );
  return res.status(200).send();
}
```

but I want to send only new added product as response
please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the $push operator [(doc)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/):

```
{ $push: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }
```

Using it with your example:

```
(async () => {
  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    '6153769ce997d65baf860cc7', 
    {
      $push: {
        products: {
          name: 'as2',
          image: '589fcd8d-f954-4aef-bd77-757af881f7c5.jpeg'
        }
      }
    }
  );
})();
```